# How to pivot a table in sql and sum the amounts?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table called test_table. This table looks like below

| id | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tax | 10 |
| 1 | premium | 21 |
| 1 | tax | 3 |
| 1 | correction | 4.5 |
| 2 | premium | 15 |

I would like to "pivot" this table and make it look like below

| id | premium | tax | correction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | 13 (=10+3) | 4.5 |
| 2 | 15 | NULL | NULL |

- create columns by type (premium, tax and correction)
- sum the amounts by type and by id

With my basic sql knowledge, I have no idea how to build this query. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Google how to do a pivot and have a go at it.  May be best to create a grouped by ID table and sum the values and pivot off that, although you can sum in the pivot

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS Sql Server, the [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) syntax should be sufficiant for this.

```
select *
from (
  select id, [type], value
  from test_table
) src
pivot (
  sum(value) 
  for [type] in ([premium], [tax], [correction]) 
) pvt
order by id
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following pivot query:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'premium'    THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS premium,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'tax'        THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS tax
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'correction' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS correction
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```

Note that the above will report zero for those cells having entry in the source table.